# How do I execute a subquery as an attribute using Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity named "Genre" that has attributes genreID and parentGenreID.  I want to make a dynamic attribute that gives me the count of Genre entities where parentGenreID is equal to the row's genreID so that I don't have to query for the count for each returned row.

If I was doing this in SQL, I'd use the query:

`SELECT g.title, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM genres sg WHERE sg.parentGenreID = g.genreID) as subgenres FROM genres g`

I was thinking perhaps a Fetched Property would be the answer, but those seem to be returned as NSArrays, and still I'm trying to figure out what the appropriate syntax would be.

My best guess is something like:

`SUBQUERY(Genre, $genre, $genre.parentGenreID = $FETCH_SOURCE.genreID).@count`

What would be the right way to do this in Core Data?

Answer (score -1):

Using `NSPredicate`, you can put condition where `parentGenreID=genreID`. Instead of using `executeFetchRequest`,use `countForFetchRequest` to get the count and again use NSPredicate `subgenres IN` with `executeFetchRequest` which returns record that contains title as you expected.

Comment: Are you suggesting using two predicates or somehow adding both parts to a single predicate?  Can you provide example code?  I'm trying to avoid running `n` additional fetch requests.